# Does Google Scholar only index the "main" version of a paper (and therefore miss terms)?

Tags: google-scholar

When I perform the search ["ND27760"](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C26&q=%22ND27760%E2%80%9D&btnG=) in GS, it does not find [this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC9626495/) from the NIH PMC free collection which cites that term in the text. Here is one possible explanation. If I search GS for the title of that paper, I get [this one result](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C26&q=allintitle%3A%22Morphometric%20imaging%20biomarker%20identifies%20Alzheimer%27s%20disease%20even%20among%20mixed%20dementia%20patients%22&btnG=). It's the nature.com (non-free) version. The term "ND27760" does not appear in the main text because it's in table 2, which requires a click to open the table on a separate page. If you click "All 6 versions" on the GS result page (at least today it was 6), the PMC paper is one of those versions.

I suspect GS, in order to conserve resources, only indexes the "main" nature.com version, and not these other versions. Is that correct?

If that's true, then GS is not indexing table content for versions that put tables on separate pages. This would be unfortunate, as tables may contain important terms. It seems the PMC versions put tables directly into the text.

EDIT 1: The above example is recent (2022). Here's a similar example from 2018. The term "ND33392" is in the text of this [PMC paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5842500/). The [GS search](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C26&q=%22ND33392%22&btnG=) for "ND33392" does not include that paper. The [GS search for the title](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C26&q=allintitle%3A%22Huntington%20Disease%20as%20a%20Neurodevelopmental%20Disorder%20and%20Early%20Signs%20of%20the%20Disease%20in%20Stem%20Cells%22&btnG=) of that paper yields one result: a [Springer publication](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s12035-017-0477-7). The Springer page does not contain the term "ND33392" in the text. It appears in table 1 which requires a click to open a new page. The PMC paper has table 1 in the text. The PMC appears in the "all N versions" link of the GS result for the Springer paper.

Comment: It is fairly recent. I believe GS will index the other versions, too, eventually.

Comment: I added an older example with similar issues.